# How to treat the processes involving propagators of two particles that mix with each other?

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, interactions, propagator

Consider a Lagrangian with two scalar particles $V,A$:

$$
L =L_{\text{kin}}(V)+L_{\text{kin}}(A)+g_{VA}VA.
$$

It looks to me that I can treat the $VA$ term either as a mixing term, diagonalizing the Lagrangian and introducing a mixing angle $\theta_{VA}\sim g_{VA}/(m_{V}^{2}-m_{A}^{2})$, or as an interaction term.

Now, consider a process that involves the $VA$ operator and where both $V$ and $A$ are virtual, connecting to each other.

The first approach tells that

$$
M = \tilde{M}\times \frac{1}{m_{A}^{2}-m_{V}^{2}}\frac{1}{p^{2}-m_{V}^{2}}
$$

where $p$ is the momentum carried by virtual $V$.

Within the second approach, I have for the matrix element

$$
M = \tilde{M}\times \frac{1}{p^{2}-m_{V}^{2}}\frac{1}{p^{2}-m_{A}^{2}}.
$$

Where am I making a mistake?